# Creating folder with PHP Google Drive API not working

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make a folder in PHP with the Google Drive API. However, when I make it, it just makes an empty file with no extension. Here is my code:

```
$user_folder = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$user_folder->setTitle("FOLDER_NAME");

$user_folder_parent = new \Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
$user_folder_parent->setId("PARENT_FOLDER_ID");
$user_folder->setParents([$user_folder_parent]);

$user_folder_upload = $this->drive_instance->files->insert($user_folder, [
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
]);
```

As far as I know this is fine but it is still not working. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I think the mimeType should also be part of the parameters of the folder like the title.  $user_folder->setmimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder'). It should be also a string parameter and not an array like in the case of the Parents.

Comment: Here you can find the information on how the request should look like. look how the json is formatted having the the mimeType at the same level than the title and parents. https://developers.google.com/drive/web/folder#creating_a_folder